# Passing a non-iterable to list.extend ()

Tags: python, list

I am creating a public method to allow callers to write values to a device, call it write_vals() for example.

Since these values will be typed live, I would like to simplify the user's life by allowing them type in either a list or a single value, depending on how many values they need to write.  For example:

```
write_to_device([1,2,3])
```

or

```
write_to_device(1)
```

My function would like to work with a flat list, so I tried to be clever and code something like this:

```
input_list = []  
input_list.extend( input_val )
```

This works swimmingly when the user inputs a list, but fails miserably when the user inputs a single integer:

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Using list.append() would create a nested list when a list was passed in, which would be an additional hassle to flatten.

Checking the type of the object passed in seems clumsy and non-pythonic and wishing that list.extend() would accept non-iterables has gotten me nowhere.  So has trying a variety of other coding methods.

Suggestions (coding-related only, please) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say that the user types in either a list or a single value, does this mean that you are receiving their input as a single string?  Do you then have to parse it for commas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `try...except...`:

```
try:
    input_list = list(input_val)
except TypeError:
    input_list = list((input_val,))
```

This is pythonic.

P.S.: Variable parameters, as [@sth proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588312/passing-a-non-iterable-to-list-extend/2588362#2588362), is much better, but I leave this answer for completeness. Sometimes you cannot use variable parameters.

Comment: I had hoped to find a less wordy solution, but this one works well.  I do like your 'list((input_val,))' trick.  Thank you!

Comment: This breaks if a single string is passed to the function, like 'abc'.

Answer (score 10):

You can check if the passed parameter is a list with the [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=isinstance#isinstance) function.

An even better solution could be to support a variable number of arguments:

```
def write_to_device(*args):
   # |args| is now a list of all the arguments given to the function
   input_list.extend(args)
```

This way multiple values can be given to the function even without having to explicitly specify them as a list:

```
write_to_device(1)
write_to_device(1,2,3)
```

Comment: If you want to pass a list to write_to_device, you can do so using *: write_to_device(*mylist)

Comment: write_to_device(*args) signify to the user that passing no write value is legal, which in this case it is not.

Comment: @JS: You could add a check like `if len(args)==0: raise TypeError('Missing arguments')`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking the type, you could use try, except.  Although, I'm curious to see how people better at python than I am would do this.

```
input_list = []
try:
    input_list.extend(input_val)
except TypeError:
    input_list.append(input_val)
```

This seems incomplete to me from an error-checking standpoint, but if you know users will only ever input a single value or a list, this will work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this, and which you choose depends on your needs.

You could try and convert the argument to a list, and assume if it doesn't work it should be interpreted as a single argument:

```
def write_to_device(args):
    try:
        args = list(args)
    except TypeError:
        args = [args]

    print args
```

This works pretty well, but you might run into problems if you pass a string as an argument:

```
>>> write_to_device(1)
[1]
>>> write_to_device([1,2])
[1, 2]
>>> write_to_device('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

You can correct for that by using `isinstance` to check if the argument is a string:

```
def write_to_device(args):
    if isinstance(args, basestring):
        args = [args]
    else:
        try:
            args = list(args)
        except TypeError:
            args = [args]

    print args
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> write_to_device(1)
[1]
>>> write_to_device([1,2])
[1, 2]
>>> write_to_device('abc')
['abc']
```

As someone noted, you *can* allow your function to take an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def write_to_device(*args):
    print args
```

Which gets you:

```
>>> write_to_device(1)
(1,)
>>> write_to_device([1,2])
([1, 2],)
>>> write_to_device('abc')
('abc',)
>>> write_to_device(*[1,2])
(1, 2)
```

My recommended way is just to require a list be passed to the function:

```
write_to_device([1])
write_to_device([1, 2, 3])
```

This is simple, straight-forward, and unambiguous.

Comment: I like your first suggestion.  Clean and elegant.  The user will be passing in a single or list of hex values, so the script blowing up if they pass a string is just desserts.  ;-)
Ok, ok. I'll check for a string and fail gracefully (grumble)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what has gone before, I created this:

```
def add2list(l,*args): l.extend(args)
# behaves like .extend, gets round issues of iterability     
# so simple, so powerful!
```

Example:

```
answer = 42
mylist = []
add2list(mylist,1)
add2list(mylist,2,3,'a','b','c',answer)
print mylist
```

Result: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 42]