# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable, Python list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops, typeerror

I am writing a program in Python and am trying to extend a list as such:

```
spectrum_mass[second] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
spectrum_intensity[second] = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
spectrum_mass[first] = [1.0, 34.0, 35.0]
spectrum_intensity[second] = [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]

for i in spectrum_mass[second]:
    if i not in spectrum_mass[first]:
        spectrum_intensity[first].extend(spectrum_intensity[second][spectrum_mass[second].index(i)])
        spectrum_mass[first].extend(i)
```

However when I try doing this I am getting `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`
 on line 3.

To be clear, `spectrum_mass[second]` is a list (that is in a dictionary, second and first are the keys), as is `spectrum_intensity[first]`, `spectrum_intensity[second]` and `spectrum_mass[second]`. All lists contain floats.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am guessing the issue is with the line -

```
spectrum_intensity[first].extend(spectrum_intensity[second][spectrum_mass[second].index(i)])
```

`extend()` function expects an iterable , but you are trying to give it a float. Same behavior in a very smaller example -

```
>>> l = [1,2]
>>> l.extend(1.2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

You want to use `.append()` instead -

```
spectrum_intensity[first].append(spectrum_intensity[second][spectrum_mass[second].index(i)])
```

Same issue in the next line as well , use `append()` instead of `extend()` for -

```
spectrum_mass[first].extend(i)
```

Comment: Good question, good answer, and I was not able to find any immediate duplicates either :). Good job.

Comment: This seems like a sensible place to link to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend) about the difference between `append` and `extend`.

Comment: I also learned something from [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2588312/2071807) on a similar subject.